Cooperative Binding and Butterfly Effect in Protein Complexes for Isotope Enrichment
Suppose a protein A with a ligand of the same element, isotopes Y and Z.
Now, many protein A's bind to various isotope Y's and Z's, each bring a small conformational change.
Afterward, protein A's with ligand filled are bonded with protein B's, which are affected by A's ligand-dependent conformation change and shift in shape further.
I hypothesized I could do this until protein G (or beyond), where much like cooperative binding and the butterfly effect, small changes in the initial ligand isotope lead to a large conformational change in the protein complex.
Has such an attempt been used to enrich isotopes? Does such a butterfly effect exist in the first place?
If different shapes can be made similar to the butterfly effect, a column chromatography setup may be used, especially if one isotope gives rise to a rod-shaped complex and the other, a ball-shaped complex.
Inspirations are the difference in human taste bud responses to deuterium oxide and protium oxide, as seen here: Does heavy water taste sweet?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
